# Change rendered HTML when state get updated React

Tags: reactjs

I have this in my App.js

```
{this.state.flightDetails.map((item)=>(
  <FlightDetails
    key={item._id}
    id={item._id}
    flightCode={item.flightCode}
    flightProvider={item.flightProvider}
    sourcePortName={item.sourcePortName}
    sourcePortCode={item.sourcePortCode}
    destinationPortName={item.destinationPortName}
    destinationPortCode={item.destinationPortCode}
    scheduledArrival={item.scheduledArrival}
    scheduledDeparture={item.scheduledDeparture}
    status={item.status}
   />
))}
```

and button to update `this.state`

```
<AddDetails handleAddDetails = {this.handleAddDetails}  />
```

as my state is like this

```
  state = {
    flightDetails: []
  }
```

when my method `handleAddDetails` get called, it does this

```
  handleAddDetails = (flightDetails) => {
    this.state.flightDetails.push(flightDetails)
    console.log(this.state.flightDetails.length)
    console.log(flightDetails)
  }
```

it does update the state. and length but where I am mapping it. Nothing adds up here. Where Am I wrong? How I can update the details in mapping area?

Comment: You're directly mutating state, never do that. Always use `setState` to update the state, have a look at some basic state management react tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You can't update `state` as you show at an example. You need to use `setState` to update your `state`.

You should do this like this:

```
  handleAddDetails = flightDetails => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      flightDetails: [...prevState.flightDetails, flightDetails]
    }));
  };
```

And when you want to add some `console.log`'s to check that your state changed properly you can do this like that:

```
  handleAddDetails = flightDetails => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        flightDetails: [...prevState.flightDetails, flightDetails]
      }),
      () => {
        console.log(`${this.state.flightDetails.length} ${flightDetails}`);
      }
    );
  };
```

By using `console.log` in the `setState` function you can be sure that `console.log` will show correct `value` after adding new elements or changing the value of `state`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always update your state by using `this.setState({...this.state.flightDetails, flightDetails});` inside the handleAddDetails() function.
By using setState the rerender will be triggered correctly.